# Match up database record with image from upload folder

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, image-uploading

I have a database with users information such as name, email etc in. When they sign up they must upload a picture. At present when they do. the image goes into a 'uploads' folder on the server.

My question is, how do i go about aligning up the database record with the corosponding image in the folder?

Comment: What do you mean "aligning up the database record"? Surely you're storing the image filename against that user in the database somehow already?

Comment: Yep, there is an 'image' field on the db that just has the file name. I guess what im trying to say is how do i pull the right image from the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the file name / url (make it unique, md5 the users ID or something) in the DB as a reference, this is the best way to handle this type of photo + user relationship.
And as normal, just save the actual file in `/uploads/`

Simply create a column in your DB called `user_photo` and save the link to the file `/uploads/john_smith_321sf.jpg`

That way in the future, you just retrieve it using your database data.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the image with something that is unique in the database. For example if 'John ' whose user id is 157 uploads an image, name the image 157.jpg - you can then query the folder for that id and extension.

Sorry, re-read the comments.

I'm assuming then that your upload file is out of the document route, is that correct? Will this help:

```
header('Content-Type: image/x-png'); //or jpg....
readfile('displayfile.png');
die();
```

Comment: And this something should be immutable. `Id` is good example, as you wouldn't change ID of particular user in future.